# Accessing a field without instantiating a class

Tags: c#, tdd, domain-driven-design

Say I have a class like this:

```
public class Offer1
    {
        private readonly Guid _id = new Guid("7E60g693-BFF5-I011-A485-80E43EG0C692");
        private readonly string _description = "Offer1";
    private readonly int _minWage = 50000;

    //Methods here
    }
```

Say I want to access the id without creating an instance of the class.  In normal situations; I would just make the field static and do this:

```
Offer1.ID //After changing the visibility to public and the name of the field to: ID
```

However, I am trying to follow DDD and TDD and I believe this is frowned upon for obvious reasons e.g. testability.  How can I approach this?

```
1) Store the ID in the configuration file and pass it to Offer1 in the constructor.  I believe this is a bad idea because it is domain information and should be in the domain model.
2) Use a static field as described above.
3) Something else
```

This is more of a design question.

Comment: Since `_id` is `readonly` I assume that every `Offer1`-object has the same id, is that correkt?

Comment: @Ackdari, yes that is correct.

Comment: perhaps you can implement a static getter method:
public static GUID ID()
{return _id;}

(this still requires _id to be static)

Comment: Does these offers have different behaviors? Furthermore, wouldn't it be helpful to see offers as entities? E.g. `offer1 = offerRepository.findById(StandardOffers.Offer1)` where `StandardOffers` is an enum. Using multiple static/singleton classes for configuration purposes doesn't seem like a very good idea. You could also have `standardOffers.offer1` where `standardOffers` is an instance of a StandardOfferFactory/Provider service (may implement `IProvideStandardOffers`).

Comment: If it is a constant value I don't see how it would affect testability when made static

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use one static field to hold the `Guid` and if every instance of `Offer1` needs a field or property for the id to referece that static `Guid`, like

```
public class Offer1
{
    internal static readonly Guid ID = new Guid(...);

    private Guid _id => ID;
    // or
    private readonly Guid _id = ID;
}
```

The propety variant has the advantage that not every instance needs memory for the `Guid`. Since `Guid` is a value-type, with a field every instance would allocated memory for the guid.

Comment: @w0051977 please mark my answer as answer if it solved your problem